# UICollectionViewCell which contains a UILabel and UIButton not recognizing touches on half the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have added a UILabel and UIButton to a UICollectionViewCell, but when touching/tapping the cell it only registers my taps on the left half the cell. Ignores any touches/taps on the right half of the cell? I should also note that it doesn't matter how long the text is in the UILabel.

EXAMPLE TEXT:

```
@"Short     text"
@"Very long text does not matter"
```

In the text above, the touches stop about where the last "t" in "text" is.

CODE:

```
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            self.clipsToBounds = YES;

            myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
            myLabel.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(myLabel.frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, SEARCH_CELL_PADDING, 0, SEARCH_CELL_PADDING +30));
            myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
            myLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
            myLabel.font = RECENT_SEARCH_CELL_FONT;
            myLabel.textColor = WK_COLOR_GRAY_77;

            myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 30)];
            myButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
            UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2.png"];
            [myButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            UIImage *btnSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
            [myButton setImage:btnSelectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [myButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

            [self addSubview:myButton];
            [self addSubview:myLabel];

        }
        return self;
    }
```

Maybe its the offsets in the cell or offsets in the uicollectionview setup?

UPDATE:

I added the following code and the tap method never gets called.

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTap)];
    [_recentSearchLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

I also changed the above code to the following:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            self.clipsToBounds = YES;

            myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
            myLabel.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(myLabel.frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, SEARCH_CELL_PADDING, 0, SEARCH_CELL_PADDING +30));
            myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
            myLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
            myLabel.font = RECENT_SEARCH_CELL_FONT;
            myLabel.textColor = WK_COLOR_GRAY_77;

            myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 30)];
            myButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
            UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2.png"];
            [myButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            UIImage *btnSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
            [myButton setImage:btnSelectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [myButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

            [self addSubview:myLabel];
            [self addSubview:myButton];


        }
        return self;
    }
```

Still **NOT** working

Comment: Can you  try adding background color to subviews & collection view cell to check the bounds ?

Comment: why this line : `[myButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];` ?

Comment: I set background colors on all subviews (label, button, etc...) The Label is on top now, @santhosh, and it still is not recognizing touches. And I also changed setUserInteractionEnabled:YES. No change.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the above code:
 [self addSubview:myButton];
 [self addSubview:myLabel];

With:
  [self addSubview:myLabel];
  [self addSubview:myButton];

Since you are adding button to the view as a subview, after that label is added as a subview which might overlap with the button position . So first add "label" as a subview and then "button". Buton will takes action now.

Hope this will solves your problem. . cheers :)

Comment: add first label as subview and then add button.. In your code ur adding "button" first and then "label".

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the collectionview was not wide enough, but somehow the cells were shooting half off the collectionviews view.  So the cells were half on the collectionview and half off. The half that was off wasn't recognizing touches.